# How to use CONCAT_WS with COALESCE?

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, coalesce, concat-ws

I have a table `users` which has fields `firstName` and `lastName`. Both of them can be NULL.

I would like to select the full name, one of them, or if both are not set then default to a string. I tried the following query, but if both of them are NULL the value is not set to `Unnamed`, but an empty string is produced instead.

```
SELECT COALESCE(CONCAT_WS(' ', firstName, lastName), 'Unnamed') AS fullName FROM users;
```

I can't use `CONCAT`, because if only one of the names is filled in, I want the single name to be returned, and `CONCAT` will return NULL if one of the values is not set.

How could I set a default value only if both of the columns are NULL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COCNAT_WS()` returns the *empty* string if all the arguments apart from the separator are `NULL`.

So, one way to do what you want is:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(CONCAT_WS(' ', firstName, lastName), ''), 'Unnamed') AS fullName
FROM users;
```

But, this might be simpler without `CONCAT_WS()`:

```
select coalesce(concat(firstName, ' ', lastName),
                firstName,
                lastname,
                'Unnamed'
               ) as fullName
```

Comment: Is this the same as Bill's answer, but with more correct explanation?

Comment: @Dharman . . . It compares the result of `CONCAT_WS()` to the empty string, not to the separator.

Comment: As  I read the manual, that won't work, depending on the `sql_mode` and/or the collation of the strings.

Answer (score 4):

Right, if both strings are NULL, then the return value is the separator, which you have set to `' '`. So you could convert that to NULL if the result of `CONCAT_WS()` is `' '`.

```
SELECT COALESCE(
  NULLIF(CONCAT_WS(' ', firstName, lastName), ' '), 
  'Unnamed'
 ) AS fullName 
FROM users;
```

Comment: Do I understand it right, that the spaces are trimmed to an empty string by MySQL? If I use empty string as the second argument to `NULLIF` it works the same as if I use string of 5 spaces.

Comment: `SELECT ''='      ' AS a;` returns true, but `SELECT '   a   '='a' AS a;` returns false. Why?

Comment: Notice `SELECT 'a'='a ';` also returns true (that is, trailing spaces are ignored). Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html for details on how trailing spaces are handled. There's a surprising amount of complexity there.